# WPF controls' authorization

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm developing a WPF client application (MVVM pattern) that exchanges data with a WCF service. I'm trying to find an effective way to handle the `IsVisibile` and `IsEnabled` properties for every control in the rendered Screen (TextBlock, TextBox, GridView, etc). In other words I need to handle what an user can see/do from an authorization perspective. I already handle the contextual `CanExecute` in the `RelayCommand`, but that's another need.

The idea is that before rendering a Screen, a remote service is called in order to get the controls' configuration for the (selected screen, current user groups). The returned data is a collection of

ControlName (string) / IsEnabled (bool) / IsVisible (bool)

This could seem weird, but the application runs on different sites, that have different Active Directory Groups, that have different meanings and different needs on each control. This architecture should allow me to make each control property configurable on the server side, removing all static references to groups name or whatever in the code.

My first idea was to apply the controls' configuration in the code-behind (at the end it's just a screen building task). I would call the service for the screen, get the component configuration from the server and than lookup the config for each `Control` in the screen. If the control name matches an element I would proceed applying the relative settings. This should be doable in few lines of code, but I suppose that `RelayCommand`s could possibly overwrite that setting afterwards.

Another idea could be to map every control to the relative properties in the ViewModel.. but I would come with a huge amount of properties in some screens and it seems to me not very maintainable.

Maybe there's a better way to do so. What could it be a good method to handle the Controls authorization?

Answer (score 5):

You could bind the `Visibility`/`IsEnabled`/`Command` properties of the elements in the view to source properties of the view model that returns `true` or `false` depending on the current user's permissions, e.g.:

```
public bool IsSaveButtonEnabled => Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("Admin");
```

This should not be handled in the code-behind of the view if you follow the MVVM pattern.

There is an example of how you could implement custom authorization in a WPF application implementing classes that derive from the `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` interfaces and overriding the application thread's default identity available here that you can refer to: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/24/custom-authorization-in-wpf/.

Returning a list of UI controls from a WCF service doesn't seem like a good approach. A service shouldn't know about any UI elements.

Comment: Thank you @mm8 for your answer. I've thought about exposing properties in VM for each control.. but there could be a huge amount of dedicated properties at the end. I was wondering whether there could be a more concise solution. The idea behind returning a list of controls from WCF is because the application must run for different independent sites. Moreover each sites has it's own AD groups (that have meaning only for that site) and its Control / Group configurations. The WCF simply return the ACLs for the current user groups returned from an SQL configuration table.

Comment: You can disable an entire panel, i.e. a group of controls, by binding its IsEnabled property.

Comment: Yes true.. but I need a deeper granularity. Anyway thanks for your time.. so far :)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I've used part of the answer provided by @mm8 in order to bind the `Visibility`/ `IsEnabled` properties of screen's Elements.

The ViewModel exposes a property of type `Dictionary<string, UserAccess>`. Each key entry represent an element access configuration. The Dictionary is filled when the screen is loaded.

Then with an Attached Property I've simplified the code writing in the view.

```
<Button 
    x:Name="btnCustomTableEditor"
    Command="{Binding NavCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="CustomTableEditor" 
    common:UserAccess.UserAccessType="{Binding AuthenticationSchema}">
```

and here the implementation of the DependencyProperty

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UserAccessProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "UserAccessType",
            typeof(Dictionary<string, UserConfiguration>),
            typeof(UserAccess),
            new PropertyMetadata(
                new PropertyChangedCallback(UserAcccessnChanged)));
```

and in the `PropertyChangedCallBack` I get a reference to the `FrameworkElement` / `Dictionary<string, UserConfiguration>`

```
private static void UserAcccessnChanged (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)d;
    Dictionary<string, UserConfiguration> myDict = 
        (Dictionary<string, UserConfiguration>)e.NewValue;
    UserConfiguration uc = myDict[frameworkElement.Name];
```

and then I can work on the Visibility / Enabled properties of the Element. Each Element must have a specified name.

I'm not sure this could be elegant, but it seems to be effective in doing its dirty work.